# Safety Razor Disposal in Medicine Cabinet

Tags: demolition

A question for the old timers(or any timers), have any of you demolished an older house that had a safety razor disposal slot built into a bathroom medicine cabinet?  Was dealing with the dispised blades any more difficult than usual?

Comment: Since your restricting answers to old timers I'll just comment that they fell to floor and I swept  them up. No problem.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease A broom cuts through my overcomplicating, thank you.

Comment: As a child I always imagined there would be millions of blades back there, but in the half dozen or so i've explored, there's usually none or a few dozen max.

Comment: There's a cute (ancient) SciFi short story where this problem is solved by installing a gadget in the back of every medicine cabinet that sends the used blades "elsewhen."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many homes had the slot to drop used razors into. I use a magnet to pick up the old razors. Even rusty they can be sharp.

I used to wrap them in a newspaper so they would not cut through the trash bags.
Today I would probably put them in some cardboard because we always have Amazon boxes to recycle.

If you find old Gillette razor blades, the coating on the blades makes a makeshift diode if you want to experiment and make a WW2 radio out of a coil of wire, an ear bud and razor blade - or that’s what my dad said. I was a sparky and we were told to rip out components, but that probably would only work on Hogan's Heroes.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I had thought through the caution part but hadn't realized the need to consider safe disposal.

Comment: Or MacGyver ......  have found many Gillette Blue blades in between studs and wrap them in newspaper. +1

Comment: +1 for the magnet. I place a piece of cardboard, (think cereal box) between the magnet and the blades. Slide the cardboard off the magnet and you have a no contact release.

Comment: I think you mean WW1; a cat's whisker crystal set. They had mass-produced superheterodyne  receivers by WW2...

Comment: I would get a sharps box, and dispose of them properly https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sharpsguard-Sharps-Bin-litre-Yellow/dp/B002ZGQ8IA

Comment: @dandavis not in POW camps, that’s why the references to hogans hero’s

Comment: A sharps box is significantly overkill. A padded envelope, newspaper (who reads those anymore?), a cardboard box of any sort, is more than enough to contain the blades and keep you from cutting yourself & the bag.